# Sharing custom video player in Google Plus' Stream

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, google-plus

Does anyone know how to embed a custom video player into the Google Plus' Stream?

You can share videos by uploading, via YouTube, or from your phone, but you can also embed the Vimeo player into the stream, for instance, by just dropping the Vimeo video's URL into the Stream.

I assume Google is parsing the markup of the URL for specific meta so that it can render it as a video, much like you can do with Facebook's Open Graph:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo

Is there a similar way to do the same with Google Plus?

Thanks!

Comment: don't know about google+, but if an vimeo url works, i think they may also be using [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) ... just saying

Comment: @pkyeck: Nice, it looks like you may be correct, judging for a quick peek at their page source: `<link rel="alternate" href="http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/25004046" type="application/json+oembed"/>` Thanks, I'll have to look into oEmbed some more.

Comment: Hi Tim, would love to know if you find a solution for this, thanks... E

Comment: Sorry, E.G., last I checked some time ago there appeared to be no way so we abandoned it for now, though it's been some time since I looked into it so things may have changed as Google+ has matured a bit more. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using schema.org markup instead: http://schema.org/VideoObject